# Get random element from array with weighted elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that represent creatures in a game I'm trying to develop. These objects have (among others) a unique identifier and a weight (or probability) to spawn.

I'm trying to develop an algorithm to spawn creatures randomly but I fail to come up with a way to use the weights (I really don't know how to do it).

Can anybody help?

An example of creatures array could be:

```
var creatures = [
    {id: 1, weight: 25},
    {id: 2, weight: 15},
    {id: 3, weight: 5},
    {id: 4, weight: 45},
    {id: 5, weight: 10}
]
```

Comment: What's the logic are you following?

Comment: what do you mean by logic? I want to retrieve a creature object (this object has a reference to the constructor of the creature) in order to create it in some scenarios

Comment: Do you wanna take a random creature out? Now how does `weight` come into play here?

Comment: Praveen meant what role do `weight` property play in the randomness of selecting elements?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't get it. The thing is, a creature has a certain chance or probability to appear. That chance is the weight. So, the more weight, the more chance to get selected.

Comment: you may have a look here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139250/random-number-generator-with-non-equal-distribution-of-numbers/41140002#41140002

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think the provided duplicated answer is too broad. There isn't even a solution in code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this nice algorithm implemented in PHP in this [blog](http://peterkellyonline.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/weighted-random-selection-in-php.html) that I think migth suit your needs.

I just adopted it to JS.

```js
var creatures = [{
    id: 1,
    weight: 25
  }, {
    id: 2,
    weight: 15
  }, {
    id: 3,
    weight: 5
  }, {
    id: 4,
    weight: 45
  }, {
    id: 5,
    weight: 10
  }],
  sumOfWeights = creatures.reduce(function(memo, creature) {
    return memo + creature.weight;
  }, 0),
  selectedWeigths = {};

function getRandom(sumOfWeights) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sumOfWeights + 1));

  return function(creature) {
    random -= creature.weight;
    return random <= 0;
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var creature = creatures.find(getRandom(sumOfWeights));
  selectedWeigths[creature.weight] = (selectedWeigths[creature.weight] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(selectedWeigths);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give an explanation as to what this does?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the algorithm is based on the discrete cumulative density function (CDF) which is the sum of the weights. The idea is to generate a random number between 0 and that sum and keep substracting to that random number the weight of the elements of the array. When it is less than zero (or zero) that means that you've found the element. It's a bit difficult to explain in just a paragraph, I suggest looking up "discrete cumulative density function" on Wikipedia, there's a much better explanation.

Comment: This solution is promising. Thanks

Comment: I find it interesting how this factory produces a scoped function that's intended solely for a single use within the `.find()` method.

Comment: Cool function! Though after some testing I do believe `Math.random() * (sumOfWeights + 1)` should be `Math.random() * sumOfWeights + 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array and add the id for each creature to the array the number of times it is weighted.  Then get a random number between 0 and the size of the array and return the id number at that position.

```
var creatureIds = [];
for(var i=0;i<creatures.length;i++){
    for(var x=0;x<creatures[i].weight;x++){
        creatureIds.push(creatures[i].id);
    }
}

// get a random index between 0 and the ids length.
var min = 0;
var max = creatureIds.length;
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

var randomWeightedCreatureId = creatureIds[index];
```

Comment: The only problem about this solution is that you end up with a big array when there might be no need to... but thanks anyway!